# positional string split in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm getting a String looking like this.

```
<Orders>13091711111100222222003333330044444400</Orders>
```

The pattern of the string is like this

```
13 - 09 - 17 - 11111 - 100 - 22222 - 200 - 33333 - 300 - 44444 - 400

year - Month -  day - Ordernumber1 -AMT- Ordernumber2 -AMT - Ordernumber3 -AMT - Ordernumber4 -AMT
```

The 1st 6 characters are fixed length(Date), followed by 8 characters for each order summary(combination of order number(5 fixed length) and amount(3 fixed length))

The number of orders can very sometimes 2 or 10 or anything.

The output should look like this using XSLT.

```
<root>
<date>130917</date>
<OrderList>
<order>
    <OrderNumber>11111</OrderNumber>
    <OrderAmount>100</OrderAmount>
</order>
<order>
        <OrderNumber>22222</OrderNumber>
    <OrderAmount>200</OrderAmount>
</order>
<order>
    <OrderNumber>33333</OrderNumber>
    <OrderAmount>300</OrderAmount>
</order>
<order>
    <OrderNumber>44444</OrderNumber>
    <OrderAmount>400</OrderAmount>
</order>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [substring](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html) for this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 1, 6)" />
```

Above will get the date.

Now you have to get al the orders, problem is that with substring you have to do this manually, like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 7, 5)" />   <!-- Order number 1 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 12, 3)" />  <!-- Order amount 1 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 15, 5)" />  <!-- Order number 2 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 20, 3)" />  <!-- Order amount 2 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 23, 5)" />  <!-- Order number 3 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 28, 3)" />  <!-- Order amount 3 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 31, 5)" />  <!-- Order number 4 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 36, 3)" />  <!-- Order amount 4 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 39, 5)" />  <!-- Order number 5 -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Orders, 44, 3)" />  <!-- Order amount 5 -->
```

---

Secondly you could do something like this in XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mypref="micorsoft.com/BizTalk/xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mypref:data">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mypref:Orders">
        <date>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 6)"/>
        </date>
        <OrderList>
            <xsl:call-template name="myOrderList">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring(., 7)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </OrderList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="myOrderList">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:param name="line-length" select="9"/>

        <order>
            <OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 1, 5)" /></OrderNumber>
            <OrderAmount><xsl:value-of select="substring($str, 6, 3)" /></OrderAmount>
        </order>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($str)&gt;$line-length">
                <xsl:call-template name="myOrderList">
                    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,$line-length)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="line-length" select="$line-length"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome !!!! Thanks Mark, that was quick. Well, but I have one problem, the script works when there are no namespaces but in my case I have a namespace in <data> node. How to fix this ?  <data xmlns="http://www.micorsoft.com/BizTalk/xslt>
<Orders>13091711111100222222003333330044444400</Orders>
</data>

Comment: Put the namespace into the stylesheet. I will adjust the answer

Comment: @Ra.one : Prepend the namespace alias to the selectors, e.g. `match="ns0:data"`, `match="ns1:Orders"` etc.